# How can I marshal a Delphi short string using p/invoke?

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a problem with a variable type from a dll which i am importing in C#. It is written in object oriented pascal and it says it is developed with the Delphi Development Tool.

On the manual of the library it says that `shortstring` is a packed array of bytes. The first byte is the length and the following are exaclty 255 bytes with the string data that i need.

So after importing the dll in C# i wrote:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
```

Then called the function from the dll:

```
public static extern byte[] xxxx();
```

But i am getting the following error:

> Cannot marshal 'return value': invalid managed/unmanaged type combination

On the other hand i tried the following:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
```

This time i get the error:

> SafeArray of rank 18727 has been passed to a method expecting an array of rank 1

Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong, and firstly is correct like this to get a shortstring from a compiled library?

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to marshal a Delphi short string is to wrap it in a struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DelphiShortString
{
    private byte length;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=255)]
    private byte[] payload;

    public string Value 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(payload, 0, length); 
        }
        set 
        {
            length = (byte)Math.Min(value.Length, 255);
            payload = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value.Substring(0, length));
        }
    }
}
```

This type is not blittable and so cannot be used as a function return value. If you have control of the Delphi code, then you can ensure that you don't use short strings as function return types. However, I suspect that you don't have control of it. In which case you'd need a blittable version of the struct. Which would look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct DelphiShortString
{
    private byte length;

    private fixed byte payload[255];

    public string Value 
    {
        get 
        {
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                fixed (byte* ptr = payload)
                {
                    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)ptr, bytes, 0, length);
                }
                return Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, length); 
            }
        }
        set 
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
            length = (byte)Math.Min(bytes.Length, 255);
            fixed (byte* ptr = payload)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, (IntPtr)ptr, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is indicative of poor design for a DLL to export a Delphi short string. That suggests that the author of the library has not designed it to be compatible with other compilers. Which in turn suggests that the functions may well use the default Delphi calling convention. Which is `register` and is not supported by Microsoft tools. If my hunch is right, then this DLL cannot be consumed directly. You would need to write an adapter DLL that exposed a more interop friendly interface.

Comment: I didn't understand the part of the return value, could you elaborate more on my type of code `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]` and function call `public static extern byte[] xxxx();`

Comment: Function return types need to be blittable value types. Arrays are not.  The blittable value version in my answer (the unsafe struct) is compatible with a Delphi short string as a return type.

Comment: I think you have an error on the line `byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value.Substring(0, length));` on the unsafe.

And secondly now how should i call the function from the dll?

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with your setter, since the length of the byte array can differ from the value of the `length` variable. In particular if the input string contains characters outside the BMP the resulting array may be shorter than the string, leading to a read-beyond-the-end bug. I'd prefer passing `Math.Min(bytes.length, 255)` to `Copy`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, that's a good point. How about the edit?

Comment: Looks fine now. I'd probably extract the encoding into a static readonly field and `MaxLength = 255` into a constant, but that's just cosmetics.

Comment: @MysticJay How should you call the function? What function? You just use one of these types when marshalling to map to a Delphi short string. I have tested this code against a Delphi DLL.

Comment: Ok it is ok now but how should apply to the marshal return value unmanaged type all i have is this: `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]; public static extern DelphiShortString xxxx();`

Comment: Remove `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]`. You don't need any marshalling attribute for these types. Just declare the function like this `public static extern DelphiShortString xxxx();` and that's it.